# Generate Gaussian Matrix in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, random, normal-distribution

I want to make a zero-mean Gaussian Matrix, *e.g.,* `M` of size (n,n) in Python such that
[image]

where, the four dimensional matrix `A` with entries [image] is given. Is there any way to do that, without changing `M` into a vector?

Comment: For each right hand side you have exactly one value left hand side. What is the point of taking mean of one value? And how it is related to gaussian? Do you just want to find `m_ij` such: `m_ij m*_lp = a_ijlp`?

Comment: @V.Ayrat This actually mean that we have the (4 dimensional) cross covariance of the random variables.